# UWP AcceptAsync(SocketAsyncEventArgs e) always return true and never call the method of SocketAsyncEventArgs.Completed

Tags: c#, uwp

Im currently developing an window app. I would like to use `AcceptAsync` method. 
At the moment there appears to be a lot of messiness in the `System.Net.Sockets.AcceptAsync(SocketAsyncEventArgs e)` always return true and
the method of `Accept_Completed` never be called.

```
private void ProcessAccept(SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
{
    e.Completed += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(Accept_Completed);
    e.AcceptSocket = null;

    bool waitFlag = listeningSocket.AcceptAsync(e);

    if (!waitFlag)
    {   //operation completed synchronously
        Accept_Completed(null, e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't just call an async function and have it run asynchronously. You need to add in the `async` keyword to your function signature and the `await` keyword to the line in which the async call is being made.

The `async` keyword in the function signature will make this function an asynchronous enabled function.

The `await` keyword tells the application where it's going to stop execution, return, and await for the async function to complete. When it completes it will go back to that `await` line and continue on with execution.

Here is a nice [MSDN article on Asynchronous programming in C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674882.aspx)

Here is an [MSDN Blog entry on Parallel Programming in .NET](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/12/async-await-faq.aspx)

For example let's say I have a function that get's data from the web asynchronously but I don't want to lock up the UI when I call it.

```
private string GetWebData(){
     return MyWebRequests.GetWebDataAsync();
}
```

Currently, my `GetWebData()` function will run synchronously because I am not implementing the C# async pattern.

In order to get this to run asynchronously we need to add in two keywords. `async`, and `await`.

```
private async string GetWebData(){
     return await MyWebRequests.GetWebDataAsync();
}
```

This will tell our application to run until the await keyword, then stop what you're doing, mark the location and exit the function. When the awaited operation finishes executing, the application will return to its marked location and continue on processing.

We're not done though, we need to add in one more thing. Since we are returning something in this async operation, we need to return a Task. In our example we need a Task. If you're not returning anything you can just set it to void.

```
private async Task<string> GetWebData(){
     return await MyWebRequests.GetWebDataAsync();
}
```

That's it!

Now let's look at your code.

```
private async void ProcessAccept(SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
{
    e.Completed += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(Accept_Completed);
    e.AcceptSocket = null;

    bool waitFlag = await listeningSocket.AcceptAsync(e);

    if (!waitFlag)
    {   //operation completed synchronously
        Accept_Completed(null, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not custum Async function, but System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AcceptAsync built in function and it is not awaitable!
https://learn.microsoft.com/lv-lv/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.acceptasync

Comment: Probably why they didnt accept the answer lol. If you have a solution I'm always open to learning and I'll upvote your answer. Thanks for clarifying this.